# Permutation of order 12 and 30 in $S_{9}$

Tags: permutations

If I have the group $S_{9}$ and $\sigma, \tau \in S_{9}$ where $\vert \sigma \vert = 5$ and $\vert \tau \vert = 6$ is it then possible to have $\vert \sigma \tau \vert = 30$ and $\vert \sigma \tau \vert = 12$ why/why not?

Comment: No element of $S_9$ has order $30$ (think about cycle types).

Comment: Not possible because $30\ne 12$...

Comment: @lhf, I took it to be two separate questions, one about order 30, another about order 12. But, who knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(12345)(234657)=(1365)(247)$.